# What do relational databases gain by setting a predefined data type for each column?

Tags: database, sql, relational-database, data-types

I'm working with an SQL database right now, and this has always made me curious, but Google searches don't turn much up: Why the strict data types?

I understand why you'd have a few different data types, for example [like how differentiating between binary and plain text data is important](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349647/does-storing-plain-text-data-take-up-less-space-than-storing-the-equivalent-mess). Rather than storing the 1s and 0s of binary data as plaintext, I now understand that it's more efficient to store the binary data as its own format.

But what I *don't* understand is what the benefit is of having *so many* different data types:

- Why `mediumtext`, `longtext`, and `text`?
- Why `decimal`, `float`, and `int`?
- etc.

What is the benefit of telling the database "There'll only be 256 bytes of plain text data in entries to this column." or "This column can have text entries of up to 16,777,215 bytes"?

Is it a performance benefit? If so, why does knowing the size of the entry before hand help performance? Or rather is it something else altogether?

Comment: I thought this question should already exist here, but I searched the site and didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Very relevant: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: If you didn't have distinct `decimal`, `float`, and `int` types, what would you expect `1 / 3` to do? What about `1.0 / 3.0`? Could you be confident that when you divide `columnA` by `columnB` that you'll get the results you expect?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser I guess I'd always validate the data before working with it. I'm vaguely familiar with the concept of doing SQL operations like that but I don't understand why I would ever actually want to. I'd query the SQL server for the entries with basic SQL, then if I want to modify it or work with it I use a more expressive language. Out of curiosity: In what scenario is it necessary to perform logical operations within SQL rather than something else like Node or Python or Ruby or PHP or something?

Comment: @johndoe I don't think it would ever be necessary, but it could be very convenient. Let's say you want to enforce a constraint that a store's inventory can't be lower than 5% of their monthly expected sales. Or you want to ensure that the total budget of each division is no more than 20% of the total budget. It could also come up in computed columns that you want to compute the same way in several applications using the same database.

Comment: It's worth noting that SQLite *doesn't* [set a predefined type per column](https://sqlite.org/datatypes.html): "SQLite is "typeless". This means that you can store any kind of data you want in any column of any table, regardless of the declared datatype of that column. "

Comment: Why Y2K? Because every byte used to matter a lot more. And yes, it still matters to performance. But no, unless you're dealing with massive amounts of data, it's not going to kill you to go with Mongo.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) is a [statically-typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) language. This means you have to know what type a variable (or field, in this case) is before you can use it. This is the opposite of dynamically-typed languages, where that is not necessarily the case.

At its core, SQL is designed to define data ([DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)) and access data ([DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language)) in a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) engine. Static typing presents several benefits over dynamic typing to this type of system.

- [Indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index), used for quickly accessing specific records, work really well when the size is fixed. Consider a query that utilizes an index, possibly with multiple fields: if the data types and sizes are known ahead of time, I can very quickly compare my predicate (WHERE clause or JOIN criteria) against values in the index and find the desired records faster.
- Consider two [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)) values. In a dynamic type system, they may be of variable size (think Java `BigInteger`, or Python's built-in arbitrary-precision integers). If I want to compare the integers, I need to know their bit length first. This is an aspect of integer comparison that is largely hidden by modern languages, but is very real at the CPU level. If the sizes are fixed and known ahead of time, an entire step is removed from the process. Again, databases are supposed to be able to process zillions of transactions as quickly as possible. Speed is king.
- SQL was designed back in the 1970s. In the earlier days of microcomputing, memory was at a premium. Limiting data helped keep storage requirements in check. If an integer never grows past one byte, why allocate more storage for it? That is wasted space in the era of limited memory. Even in modern times, those extra wasted bytes can add up and kill the performance of a CPU's cache. Remember, these are database engines that may be servicing hundreds of transactions per second, not just your little development environment.
- Along the lines of limited storage, it is helpful to be able to fit a single record in a single page in memory. Once you go over one page, there are more page misses and more slow memory access. Newer engines have optimizations to make this less of an issue, but it is still there. By sizing data appropriately, you can mitigate this risk.
- Moreso in modern times, SQL is used to plug in to other languages via [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) or [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) or some other layer. Some of these languages have rules about requiring strong, static types. It is best to conform to the more strict requirements, as dynamically-typed languages can deal with static types easier than the other way around.
- SQL supports static typing because database engines need it for performance, as shown above.

It is interesting to note that there are implementations of SQL that are *not* strongly-typed. [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) is probably the most popular example of such a relational database engine. Then again, it is designed for single-threaded use on a single system, so the performance concerns may not be as pronounced as in e.g. an enterprise Oracle database servicing millions of requests per minute.

Comment: SQLite has datatypes that do distinguish between numeric and text data, but only has 5 "classes" of data storage: https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I know, but it is still nowhere near as strict as engines like SQL Server, Oracle, or PostgreSQL.

Comment: Not only is SQL statically-typed - due to the presence of check constraints, it effectively supports refinement types.

Comment: Though implied in the first bullet `Indexes`, more basically stated: Having a data type allows the database engine to **make sense of the data**, to make comparisons (bigger/smaller numbers, earlier/later date-times, before/after in the alphabet), and therefore **enables sorting and querying**.

Comment: So if sizes are important... and sql needs to know beforehand... what's the exact size of a "Zillion" transactions?

Comment: @WernerCD That's the wrong kind of size. To work with memory regions in C, you must know beforehand the size of the region -- but it is not necessary to know the exact number of CPU cycles required to run the C program in full.

Answer (score 24):

**First: plain text is binary** (it's not even the UTF8 or ASCII characters "0" and "1" but actual on/off bits)

That said, some of the reasons are:

- **Business/design constraints:** allowing the number 7626355112 in the HEIGHT column of the PERSON table would be wrong. Allowing "Howya" in the DATE column of an INVOICE would be wrong.
- **Less error prone code:** you don't have to write code to make sure the data retrieved from a date column is really a date. If column types were dynamic you would have to make a lot of type checks when reading them.
- **Computing efficiency:** If a column is of type INTEGER, and you SUM() it, the RDBMS doesn't have to apply floating point arithmetics.
- **Storage efficiency:** stating that a column is VARCHAR(10) lets the RDBMS allocate space more precisely.
- **Referential integrity and unicity:** PK (or FKs) of a table shouldn't allow floats, since floating point equality is tricky, so you must declare them in a non-float type, like characters or integer.
- **There exist RDBMSs whith dynamic (not strict) column types (SQLite)**. It uses the concept of "type affinity" while still allowing you to insert  virtually anything into any column without complaining. There are trade-offs that wil not be discussed here. See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278394/would-sqlite-be-less-useful-without-accepting-inserts-of-non-numeric-values-into).

Answer (score 8):

It is so that the underlying code that the database is written in can allocate and use fixed size records, if it knows that a specific field can contain 0 to 256 characters of text then it can allocate a block of 256 bytes to store it in.

This makes things much faster, e.g. you are not having to allocate additional storage as the user types, since a given field always starts x bytes into the record a search or select on that field knows to always check x bytes into each record, etc.

Comment: If only all answers could be this concise and to-the-point...

Answer (score 6):

When the columns of a database are given defined types, the types are usually defined themselves to have a certain size in bits. As a result:

1) when the database engine is traversing the rows in a table it doesn't have to do any fancy parsing to determine where each record ends, it can just know that each row consists of, say, 32 bytes, and so to get the next record it's sufficient to add 32 bytes to the current records location.

2) when looking up a field within a row, it is possible to know an exact offset for that field again without parsing anything, so column lookups are a simple arithmetic operation rather than a potentially costly data processing one.

Comment: Fixed-length fields can make processing more efficient because of consistent record lengths and field offsets, but variable-length fields  can nullify those benefits because the record length and offset of fields can vary. Similarly, record-level compression will result in variable-length records, so the location of a given record can't simply be calculated.

Comment: This is true, and it was common advice for a long time to avoid variable length fields for exactly that reason. I don't know how the big players do it but it seems like you might be able to recapture some of the benefits of fixed length by having the engine store variable width fields in a not-user-visible table or memory block and have the primary tables representation of those fields be a (fixed width) 'pointer' into it. Considering you should be regularly doing full scans of variable length fields in the first place the indirection's performance hit might be worth maintaining fixed widths.

Answer (score 3):

*In general,* the more detail you tell the database about what you're storing, the more it can try to optimize various performance metrics related to that data, such as how much space to allocate on disc or how much memory to allocate when retrieving it.

> Why mediumtext, longtext, and text?

Not sure which database your using *so I will have to guess:* I'd guess that two of these datatypes have upper limits, one of them does not. Using datatypes for text that have upper limits tell the database how much storage space it will need for each record. It's also possible that some databases might have different ways of storing large (possibly unlimited) text vs. small fixed-length text (this may vary by database, check your manual to see about yours).

> Why decimal, float, and int?

Different levels of precision require different amounts of storage, and not every use requires highest degrees of precision. For example, see here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950

Oracle has a quite a number of different numeric types with different storage requirements and different capabilities in terms of level of precision and size of number that can be represented.

Answer (score 3):

You asked *why* DBMSs have static data types.

1. Speed of lookup. The whole point of a DBMS is to store far more data than you could possibly load into a program. Think "all the credit card slips generated in the world in the last ten years". In order to search such data efficiently, fixed length data types are helpful. This is especially true for structured data  like date stamps and account numbers. If you know what you're dealing with ahead of time, it's easier to load into efficient indexes.
2. Integrity and constraints. It's easier to keep data clean if it has fixed data types.
3. History.  RDBMSs got started when computers had but a few megabytes of RAM, and terabyte-scale storage was enormously expensive. Saving a dozen bytes in each row of a table could save thousands of dollars and hours of time under those circumstances.
4. The curse of the customer base. RDBMSs today are very complex, highly optimized, software packages, and they have been in use for decades accumulating data. They're mature. They work. A RDBMS crash resulting in large scale data loss is vaninshingly rare these days. Switching to something with a more flexible data typing system isn't worth the cost or risk to most organizations.

Analogy: it may be blindlying obvious that urban subway systems would work better (quieter, faster, more power-efficient) on a narrower rail gauge.  But how are you going to change all the rails in the New York City subway system to realize those improvements? You aren't, so you optimize what you have.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, it's historical.

Once upon a time, tabular data was stored in files composed of fixed-length records in turn composed of pre-defined fields such that a given field was always of the same type and in the same place in each and every record. This made processing efficient and limited the complexity of coding.

Add some indexes to such a file and you have the beginnings of a relational database.

As relational databases evolved, they began to introduce more data types and storage options, including variable-length text or binary fields. But, this introduced variable-length records, and broke the ability to consistently locate records via calculation or fields via a fixed offset. No matter, machines are much more powerful today than they were back then.

Sometimes it's useful to set a specific size for a field to help enforce some bit of business logic - say 10 digits for a North American phone number. Much of the time it is just a bit of computing legacy.

Answer (score 1):

If a database uses fixed-sized records, any record in the database will continue to fit, in the same location, even if its contents are changed.  By contrast, if a database tries to store records using exactly the amount of storage needed for their fields, changing Emma Smith's name to Emma Johnson may cause her record to be too big to fit in its present location.  If the record is moved to someplace with enough room, any index that keeps track of where it is would need to be updated to reflect the new location.

There are a variety of ways to reduce the cost associated with such updates.  For example, if the system maintains a list of record numbers and data locations, that list will be the only thing that would need to be updated if a record moves.  Unfortunately, such approaches still have significant cost (e.g. keeping a mapping between record numbers and locations would require that record retrieval would require an extra step to retrieve the data associated with a given record number).  Using fixed-sized records may seem inefficient, but it makes things a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

For a lot of what you do as a web developer, there is no need to understand what's happening "under the hood". There are times, however, when it helps.

> What is the benefit of telling the database "There'll only be 256 bytes of plain text data in entries to this column." or "This column can have text entries of up to 16,777,215 bytes"?

As you suspect, the reason is to do with efficiency. [The abstractions leak](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/). A query like [`SELECT author FROM books`](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) can run quite quickly when the size of all fields in the table are known.

As Joel says,

> How does a relational database implement `SELECT author FROM books`? In a relational database, every row in a table (e.g. the books table) is exactly the same length in bytes, and every fields is always at a fixed offset from the beginning of the row. So, for example, if each record in the books table is 100 bytes long, and the author field is at offset 23, then there are authors stored at byte 23, 123, 223, 323, etc. What is the code to move to the next record in the result of this query? Basically, it’s this:
>
> `pointer += 100;`
>
> One CPU instruction. Faaaaaaaaaast.

A lot of the time, you're working far enough away from the nitty gritty underpinnings that you don't need to care about it. As a PHP-based web dev, do you *care* about how many CPU instructions your code uses? Most of the time, no, not really. But sometimes it's useful to know, for two reasons: it can explain decisions made by your libraries; and sometimes you do need to care about speed in your own code.